# Laravel PDO exception

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo, laravel

I have installed xampp and laravel.

Migration went all, everything is working, so there exist connection to the mysq server.

Although when i try to

```
Schema::create('tickets', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('summary');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('priority',1)->default('3');
        $table->datetime('due_at')->nullable();
        $table->datetime('closed_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

The following error appears

'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/....

Don't know what to do, since I've tried everything.

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: I haven't used Laravel but you should probably edit the question and explain: 1) If you've installed the PDO driver for MySQL 2) How you instruct Lavarel to use MySQL

Comment: seems like your lampp does not deliver PDO lib, check phpinfo()

Comment: i've checked phpinfo() - API Extensions mysqli,mysql,pdo_mysql

The laravel use mysq by the configurations in database.php i think.

Comment: You've typed `mysq` several times. Is it possible that you also mistyped it in the `database.php` file?

Comment: I'v checked, is ok.

tried DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();

Same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should install PDO on your server. Edit your php.ini (look at your `phpinfo()`, "Loaded Configuration File" line, to find the php.ini file path). Find and uncomment the following line (remove the `;` character):

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Then, restart your Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

If not works means Modify the File AppServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```